# Confused with setting up Segment Registers

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, bootloader, bios

I am working on a writing a boot loader and the tutorial I am following provides this code:

```
main:

 ;----------------------------------------------------
 ; code located at 0000:7C00, adjust segment registers
 ;----------------------------------------------------

      cli                       ; disable interrupts
      mov     ax, 0x07C0                ; setup registers to point to our segment
      mov     ds, ax
      mov     es, ax
      mov     fs, ax
      mov     gs, ax

 ;----------------------------------------------------
 ; create stack
 ;----------------------------------------------------

      mov     ax, 0x0000                ; set the stack
      mov     ss, ax
      mov     sp, 0xFFFF
      sti                       ; restore interrupts
```

I may be misunderstanding something but if the SS register contains 0x0000 wouldn't that mean that the That the ds, es, fs, and gs would overlap the stack? Also what are the functions of the fs and gs registers? Also, is the cs segment set automatically by the BIOS? Because it says that the code is located at 0000:7c00. Also, the tutorial never goes over why interrupts are disabled. I read somewhere that interrupts are usually disabled to avoid deadlock. What does this mean and why does it happen?

Comment: Just an observation: Your code will only work on 386 and higher processors. The 8086/8088/80286 didn't have the `FS` and `GS` segment registers. This may be by design but I just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 8):

At least in theory, yes, the stack and code could overlap. The reason they don't is pretty simple: the bootloader is pretty small, and won't normally use much stack space, so the stack never grows downward far enough to overwrite the end of the bootloader code.

As far as fs and gs go, they don't really have any dedicated uses. Without looking at the code for the boot-loader in question, it's open to question whether they're used at all. If they are used, it's open to still more question what they'd be used *for*.

The disk BIOS loads a sector from the disk into 07c00:0000h, and does a far jump to it. The far jump sets `cs`.

You disable interrupts while setting up the stack because executing an interrupt (attempts to) push data onto the stack. If you haven't set the stack up yet (both SS and SP) you generally don't even know where in memory that data (flags and return address) might end up, or what other data it might overwrite. That's generally undesirable, so you disable interrupts at least until SS and SP are both set up.

Comment: With the exception of ancient buggy 8088 processors(some exist), the Interrupt flag is turned off (temporarily) during the update of ANY segment register for the duration of the instruction and until the end of the *following* instruction. If you update SS and then follow it with an instruction that updates SP right after then the interrupts would be off during both. As of the 286(and higher) the only register where interrupt flag is turned off temporarily like this is the SS register.

Comment: Because of the possibility of encountering a buggy 8088 processor it is generally advised to turn interrupts off explicitly.

Comment: You said _The disk BIOS loads a sector from the disk into 07c00:0000h_. I assume that is a typo and should be _07c0:0000h_ or _0000:7c00_ (or anything equivalent). If you don't write position independent code (ie. you perform non-far absolute JMPs and CALLs) you can't assume the BIOS jumped to your code setting the correct `CS` (since there are many combinations of segment:offset) that map to same physical address. If your code isn't position independent then one can do a FAR JMP to a label in the code setting CS appropriately.